# An onto function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Does there exist an onto function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$? If $f$ is required to be linear then the answer is no, this follows from basic ideas of linear algebra.

In the case where we allow for $f$ to be an arbitray function, I believe the answer is that yes, such a function $f$ does exist, simply because the domain and codomain both have the same cardinality (uncountably infinite) and thus there is a bijection between the two.

How far does this generalize? If it is true then it must also be true that for each $n$ there exists a function $f$ such that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is onto.

What about $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

What about $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^I$ where $I$ is an uncountable infinite set?

Thank you.

Comment: "*then it must also be true that $f~:~\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$ is true for all $n$*"  This phrase is malformed.  Surely you mean to say that it must also be true *that for all $n$ there exists a surjective $f$* such that yada yada...

Comment: Be careful!  "Uncountably infinite" isn't a cardinal -- there are no bijection between $A$ and $P(A)$ for any uncountably infinite $A$ despite both being uncountably infinite.

Comment: The Peano curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve) is one place to start - this doesn't do everything you want but it is a big start and does something extra - in going from one dimension to two it manages to be continuous. The same idea can be extended.

Comment: Considering that space filling curves exist, you could even have a continuous function do this (I thin)

Comment: @MarkBennet Figures, start a comment then get called up to go help a student with basic algebra, should have checked updates before finishing it!

Comment: For any infinite cardinal $C$ we have $C \cdot \aleph_0 = C.$ So there is indeed a bijective correspondence between $\Bbb R$ and countably infinitely many copies of $\Bbb R.$ If you allow infinitely many copies to come into the picture then this can only hold if the indexing set $I$ you have started with has cardinality same as the cardinality of the continuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Finite case

Yes, it is true that for each $n \in \Bbb N$, there exists a function $f_n : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$ which is onto.
This is simply because $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ have the same cardinality and thus, by induction, so does $\Bbb R^n$. This means that there exists a *bijection* from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^n$.

#### Countable case

This is again true. As earlier, $\Bbb R^\Bbb N$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$.
Here's a sketch of the proof: Show that $\{0, 1\}^\Bbb N \cong \Bbb R$ ($\cong$ denotes bijection of sets) and hence note
$$\Bbb R^\Bbb N \cong \{0, 1\}^{\Bbb N \times \Bbb N} \cong \{0, 1\}^\Bbb N \cong \Bbb R.$$

#### Uncountable case

As noted in the comments, simply saying that $I$ is uncountable does not tell us the cardinality of $I$. For example, $|I|$ could be $|\Bbb R|$ or $|\cal P(\Bbb R)|$ (or something else altogether).

I suspect that you wished to say $I \cong \Bbb R$. In this case, note that
$$|\Bbb R^\Bbb R| \ge |\{0, 1\}^\Bbb R| = |\cal P(\Bbb R)|.$$
It is a standard (and easy) theorem that there is no surjection from any set onto its power set. Thus, we see that there's no onto function from $\Bbb R$ onto $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$.